# How to implement ListView in ReactNative with custom cell component?

Tags: javascript, listview, reactjs, react-native

I am building a ReactNative + Redux app and am using the `ListView` component.

In `_renderRow()` of the `ListView`, I'd like to return my own cell component (called `JobDetailCell` that only receives the data in its `props` from the component that is managing the `ListView` (called `JobsRootComponent`).

I came up with the following code so far:

#### JobsRootComponent.js

```
import React, {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  ListView,
  ActivityIndicatorIOS,
  NavigatorIOS,
  TouchableHighlight
} from 'react-native'

import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'
import { fetchJobs } from '../actions/Actions'
import { JobDetailCell } from './JobDetailCell'
import { JobDetailComponent } from './JobDetailComponent'

class JobsRootComponent extends Component {

  ...

  _renderRow(rowData) {
      const title = rowData.title
      const subtitle = rowData.by
      return (
        <JobDetailCell title={title} subtitle={subtitle}></JobDetailCell>
      )
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
        <ListView
          style={styles.container}
          dataSource={this.props.dataSource}
          renderRow={this._renderRow}
        />
      )
  }

  ...

}
```

#### JobDetailCell.js

```
import React, {
  Component,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} from 'react-native'

export default class JobDetailCell extends Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.cellContainer}>
        <Text style={styles.cellTitle}>{this.props.title}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.cellSubtitle}>{this.props.subtitle}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }

}
```

However, when I am running the app, I get the following errors in the chrome dev console:

> **ExceptionsManager.js:76 Warning:**
>
> `React.createElement`: type should not
>   be `null`, `undefined`, `boolean`, or `number`. It should be a `string` (for DOM
>   elements) or a `ReactClass` (for composite components). Check the `render`
>   method of `StaticRenderer`.

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please add the import/require section of the files, these kind of problems rely in that part a lot of the time.

Comment: sure, I updated the post and added the imports.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing your components in the wrong way.

This line

```
import { JobDetailCell } from './JobDetailCell'
```

Is equivalent to this line:

```
var JobDetailCell = require('./JobDetailCell').JobDetailCell;
```

Which gets undefined since you exported the component itself, which has no field named `JobDetailCell`.

This is how you should import your component:

```
import JobDetailCell from './JobDetailCell'
```

Comment: Wasted hours behind it and then finally. Thank you.